How can I properly assign a macro to a shape?
I have a workbook called BOOK1 and in that a sheet called TEST and a shape called TESTSHAPE. In the vba code for the sheet I have the following code which alows the user to click on the shape and cycle through colours.
  Dim sh As Shape
   Set sh = Me.Shapes(Application.Caller)
   
   
  'If red go black
If sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 1, 2) Then
sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
sh.Fill.Transparency = 0.45
sh.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(198, 0, 241)
sh.Line.Visible = False

'If black go white
ElseIf sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
sh.Fill.Transparency = 0.95
sh.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(198, 0, 241)
sh.Line.Visible = False

'If white go red
ElseIf sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
sh.Fill.Transparency = 0.55
sh.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(198, 0, 241)
sh.Line.Visible = False


ElseIf sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 200, 20)
sh.Fill.Transparency = 0.55
sh.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(198, 0, 241)
sh.Line.Visible = False

Else
sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
sh.Fill.Transparency = 0.89
sh.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(198, 0, 241)
sh.Line.Visible = False
End If

End Sub

It works fine but if I copy the sheet to a new workbook for example BOOK2, the macro assigned to the shape stops working as it is still linked to the sheet in the first book. Then I have to manually re assign the macro
When I rename the macro to the name of the sheet the macro link for the shape becomes TEST.One_Click which makes sense but after copying the sheet to BOOK2 the link becomes !BOOK1.TEST.One_Click which obviously doesn't work in BOOK2.
How do I make sure it stops referencing the book and stays with the sheet only
Is there a way I can completely contain the macro within the sheet so that it can be copied to other books and still work without the user having to deal with macros?

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/fix-shape-macro-links-after-copying-worksheet/

Maybe try adding this to the worksheet code module where Tester lives:
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim shp As Shape, arr, el
    'list of macros to re-link
    arr = Array("Tester", "DoSomething", "LastOne")
    For Each shp In Me.Shapes
        Debug.Print shp.OnAction
        For Each el In arr
            If InStr(shp.OnAction, el) > 0 Then
                shp.OnAction = Me.CodeName & "." & el
                Exit For 'stop checking this shape
            End If
        Next el
    Next shp
End Sub

Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print "Tester"
End Sub
Sub DoSomething()
    Debug.Print "DoSomething"
End Sub
Sub LastOne()
    Debug.Print "LastOne"
End Sub

It will re-assign any shapes whose OnAction points to one of the macros listed in arr.
You could alternatively just check any shape for an OnAction, and replace the first part:
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim shp As Shape, a, arr
    For Each shp In Me.Shapes
        a = shp.OnAction
        If Len(a) > 0 Then
            arr = Split(a, ".")
            shp.OnAction = Me.CodeName & "." & arr(UBound(arr))
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub


Hi there, Thanks for that it worked perfectly. How would I go about modifying it so that it assigns certain shapes to one macro and certain shapes to another? I was thinking of adding an If inside your code to check for certain shape names in an array?

Do you only need to re-assign existing links?  If the problem was with the sheet being copied I assume the shapes are all already linked?

Yes the shapes are already linked. But if i have two types of shape with a different macro each I want it to be able to re link both.

Second example above will re-link any shape which already has a link.
